# Generating a GraphQL schema from a JSON schema in GoLang

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen, graphql-go

I am new to Go and GraphQL and was wondering if it is possible to programmatically build the schema from a JSON schema fetched from an endpoint.

I am currently looking to use [gqlgen](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen) which allows for manually defining your schema via SDL (Schema Definition Language) in `schema.graphqls` file. This package support many of the features graphql-go seems to be missing and is actively maintained.

I've looked into [graphql-go](https://github.com/graphql-go/graphql) which allows me to do this but that package seems to be abandoned and is missing support for certain features.